# Autostart Dropbox in Lubuntu

Tags: dropbox, lubuntu, autostart

I've installed Dropbox (as per the instructions supplied in [Dropbox's Home Page](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx)  and a personal blog I found browsing about the subject), but still no success in forcing autostart (only for my user) on dropboxd. I've tried adding an autostart file in:

But no success so far... I have to start it manually. I don't want to edit the file in:

> /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart

The file plainly states:

> ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd

as I have understood, would add autostart for Dropbox for all users...

Any ideas about what went wrong?

---

*Edit: both the links mentioned above seem non-functional.*

Comment: What about adding Dropbox to the Startup Applications list?

Answer (score 5):

That is different solution, which works in Ubuntu 11.10:

You will need start-up [script](https://gist.github.com/861875). 
Save it to /etc/init.d/dropbox

```
groupadd dropbox
usermod -aG dropbox root
chmod +x /etc/init.d/dropbox
update-rc.d dropbox defaults
```

Change **root** in second code line above with your needs. Make sure you don't forget the -a switch in usermod - especially when you use

Run Dropbox manually for first time

```
/root/.dropbox-dist/dropbox
```

Change command above with your environment.

Copy URL it gives you (do not stop or interrupt program, just copy URL). 
Paste the URL to the Browser, confirm password. 
You will see Dropbox confirmation, that it is connected. 
Now you can interrupt Dropbox by *Ctrl+C*. 
Reboot to try autostart.
If it not starts, run Dropbox manually once again and look up for any messages or errors.

Answer (score 2):

For per-user autostart, use the `~/.config/lxsession/<profile>/autostart` file. For more info see the [LXDE wiki](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession#autostart)

Comment: That is the one I'm using right now, but it doesn't work, however, another option has been suggested for this [query](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604211)...

Answer (score 1):

solved here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11108807&postcount=8

> In order to get Dropbox to autostart at logon, I did this: made a new
>   file in my autostart folder here:
>
> ```
> /home/GUS/.config/autostart
> ```
>
> (you should change GUS to whatever your own username is) Call the file
>   `Dropbox.desktop` Open it in your text editor and paste these lines,
>   again changing GUS to your username in the line that starts with
>   "Exec":
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Encoding=UTF-8
> Name=Dropbox
> Comment=RunDropbox
> Icon=/usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/dropboxstatus-logo.svg
> Exec=bash /home/GUS/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
> Terminal=false
> Type=Application
> ```
>
> Save it. Logout. Login. Be happy.
>
> By the way, in order to get dropbox installed, I followed the
>   instructions here:
>   http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/04/how-to-install-dropbox-in-lubuntu