# Dropbox 1.6.1 doesn't link to account

Tags: dropbox

For the life of me, I can't seem to get Dropbox installed in such a way that it links to my account and starts syncing files. I've tried the following:

1. `sudo apt-get install dropbox`
2. `sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox`
3. install from (1) .deb (2) CLI per https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=linux
4. installing from dropbox repo per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251170/dropbox-wont-start-anymore)

A couple of these methods had me running `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`. I was expecting to see the url to link the account at some point, but every time I ran this command, there was no output, although the icon would pop up.

When I click the dropbox icon, it just says "Connecting..." even though it never queries me for credentials.

I even tried installing using ubuntu-tweak to see if that would work. I got a dependency error with that, so I couldn't really find out.

Comment: I had the same problem. The only thing I found to work was to just install version 2.6.5 instead. You can download it from [this forum post](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=111162).

Comment: This is happening to me too maybe it is a bug  I am running both 13.10 and 14.04

Comment: @MuffinSpawn Installing with the new version resolved the problem. Although it's not a fix to the issue I was experiencing, I don't see any reason why anyone would want to preserve the old version, so if you make your response an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Also, if someone else chooses to download the 2.6.5 version rather than using Ubuntu default 1.6.1, and you want to register dropbox as a service, follow the instructions posted by Alvin Row in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47532/autostart-dropbox-in-lubuntu?rq=1). The script works the same in Ubuntu as Lubuntu.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to start dropbox on startup, you can add `bash -c "sleep 20s && ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd"` to your **Startup Applications**. The icon didn't show up for me until I incorporated the sleep command. You can also put the same command in your crontab as `@reboot <cmd>`.

Comment: So, you are saying that this is a bug with the Ubuntu version of Dropbox?

Comment: @Mack I suggest you add your own answer since MuffinSpawn hasn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a solution to the issue with Dropbox version 1.6.1. However, installing version 2.6.5 from [this link](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=111162) did resolve the issue.

```
wget https://dl-web.dropbox.com/u/17/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-2.6.5.tar.gz
tar xzvf dropbox-lnx.x86_64-2.6.5.tar.gz
```

The files will be removed from the archive and placed in the appropriate location for you. Keep in mind, this is not (as far as I know), available from the Ubuntu repos, so you'll need to do a few extra steps to set it up properly.

1. Set up Dropbox as a service by following Alvin Row's instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47532/autostart-dropbox-in-lubuntu?rq=1)
2. If you want Dropbox to start on system start, add `bash -c "sleep 20s && ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd"` to your **Startup Applications**. Alternatively, add the same command as an `@reboot` task in your crontab. You can try it without the sleep portion, but the icon didn't show up for me unless I included it.

Comment: for ubuntu 13 x64, I solved with version 2.10.41 https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=121698