# Running Dropbox at startup

Tags: command-line, startup, dropbox

Please excuse a simple question from a new Linux user.
Running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5800 @ 3.20GHz × 2.

I installed **Dropbox** OK with the command:

```
   cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

as suggested by the **Dropbox** web site, which worked fine.

Then the **Dropbox** daemon was run with the command:

```
  ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Again this worked well, **Dropbox** runs in the background giving easy access to my cloud data.

The Problem

How can I automatically run the **dropbox** daemon when the session is restarted? Current workaround is to open a terminal and enter the command:

```
  ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Many thanks

Comment: Take a look at this question and see if that helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47532/autostart-dropbox-in-lubuntu

Comment: Are you using any DE?. Is this just a server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and solve it by installing dropbox following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/126208/104253), but substituting `nautilus-dropbox` by `dropbox`. That is, I installed dropbox by executing these commands:

> ```
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
>
> sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install dropbox
> ```

Comment: If that worked for you, you may also click to upvote my answer.

Comment: I think I have done that now. Pl let me know otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

I installed dropbox from the app provided in the Ubuntu Software Centre and works well placing an icon in the top bar of the screen.

Comment: I tried this but the Ubuntu Software Centre totally hung half way though. Had to reinstall the Software Centre to regain control. Thanks anyway.